# What is the replacement for the child selector?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, css-selectors

Since IE6 does not support the child selector (see http://kimblim.dk/csstest/#ex1), what is the alternative when dealing with this browser?

I do not want to modify the markup, and I'd much much prefer a CSS-only solution...

And yes, it is the direct child that I wish to target.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've come across something of a hack: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2005/05/31/universal-child-replacement/
Using the '[star html](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/poll/star-html.php)' hack for IE (6 and below) in combination with this allows me to select the direct child. Let's say we want to apply a padding-top of 10px to the direct child, F, of E:

```
* html body E F
{
    /* apply style here for IE 6 */
    padding-top: 10px;
    /* This applies the style to every F inside of E */
}
* html body E * F
{
    /* undo style here */
    padding-top: 0px;
    /* This will undo the style set above for every F that has something in between itself and E, that is, every F besides the direct children of E */
}
```

I do appreciate your responses so far but as much as I hate to accept my own answer, this was the solution I eventually settled on. Thanks guys!

Comment: Unfortunately this answer isn't perfect. It works but as the descendant children it could cause problem too...

let say you have a 3 nested div. you want to change the second div to a padding of 20px while the third div has a padding of 5px. You could have this rule that puts every other children to a padding of 4 px. But let say you have an other div to 7px...you can't just put the value back to something else. It can work but you still have too look for unforseen consequences...

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery, not a pretty solution, but it is one option that I have used in the past:

```
$("parent > child").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("child-styles");
}
```

You are obviously going to want to wrap this in some specialized IE6 only check.  And probably want a style sheet wrapped in the IE6 IF statement to add these specialized styles.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good solution I have found in a book: "The Anthology of Javascript"

Something like that:

```
/* for all but IE */
#nav ul li.currentpage > a:hover {
  background-color: #eff;
}
```

And the code to cater for IE:

```
/* for IE */
* html #nav ul li.currentpage a:hover {
  background-color: expression(/currentpage/.test(this.parentNode.className)? "#eff" : "#ef0");
}
```

The hack for IE is that only IE thinks that there is a wrapper over html, and IE does support the expression() stuff.

The expression uses a regular expression (/currentpage/), and tests it against the class of the parent node, so the direct children of the element li.currentpage will be set to #eff, the other descendants will be set to #ef0.

Note that the colours used are fake, please do not comment on them ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, CSS expressions are no longer supported in IE8 standards mode... (http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/10/16/ending-expressions.aspx)

Comment: @Ryann: IE8 supports the child selector natively, so this IE6-hack being ignored/no longer functional in IE8 should be no problem

Answer (score 1):

This post discusses all of the different options for emulating CSS child selectors in IE6, including a little trick at the end to work with nested structures: http://craftycode.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/emulating-css-child-selectors-in-ie6/

Answer (score 0):

Do you need direct child?  IE6 supports descendant selectors like

```
div span { ... }
```

Perhaps you could leverage that to target what you want.  Perhaps you could post some code so that we could give you a more specific answer?

Comment: no they mean "parent > child" where it only uses direct children and not all children.

Comment: yes I understood - if you can be clever about it sometimes using normal descendant selectors can work in a pinch

Answer (score 0):

Putting a custom class on the element.

```
<ul>
<li class="first">Blah<li>
<li>Blah<li>
<li>Blah<li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is a fix for the :first-child issue, not >.

Comment: One could put a class on all first childs, but then beware though, if you have nested lists (which is very likely when worried about matching non-direct childs), you must use a different class name for each one. Otherwise `ul li.child` will match both, which is not intended probably: `<ul><li class="child"> <ul><li class="child"></li></ul> </li></ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
div * { padding-left:20px; }
div * * { padding-left:0; }
```

First you target all children, and then you reset the css declaration by targeting all grandchildren.

Answer (score 0):

A cross-browser solution that I have used is the following. It doesn't use IE6 hacks and displays embedded lists correctly (say you need to style OL and UL nested items differently).

```
ul, ol {
    /* Set margins, padding, and other generic styles */
}
ul li, ul ul li, ol ul li {
    list-style-type: disc; /* unordered lists */
}
ol li, ul ol li, ol ol li {
    list-style-type: decimal; /* ordered lists */
}
```

It's as easy as yodeling CSS!

Comment: This answer doesn't seem related to the question. Also, wouldn't "ul { list-style-type: disc; } ol { list-style-type: decimal; }" do exactly the same ? Why all the yodeling ?