# Child selector in IE6 hack

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, css-selectors

I am trying to show another UL within an Li in IE 6 which is a dropdown menu. Here's what I have.

```
ul.dropdown li:hover > ul 
{
visibility: visible;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
width: 92px;
background-color: #eeeeee;
 }
```

Now this does not work in IE6 and I wanted to know if there is a fix/hack for this without using Javascript.

I found [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436702/what-is-the-replacement-for-the-child-selector) but somehow I think that my :hover is interfering with this.

Can someone help please?

Thanks!

Comment: IE6 does not support either `li:hover` or `>`, so it'd be more than just working around the child selector issue.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock...I think the li:hover is what's throwing me. Otherwise, I think I managed to find a solution for the > child selectors. Apparently you can use something, like Eric Meyer's ul.dropdown a.admin-menu:hover * ul to get around this but this I am still testing. Anyone know if something like this will work?

Comment: To make IE6 support `:hover`, try [Whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html). But that won't help with the `>` selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution is to use jQuery from the example we're using. Thanks guys

Comment: You said that, if I use the `ul.dropdown li:hover > ul` selector in jQuery, it will work in IE6?